# Adjunction formula for singular hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $Y$ is a singular hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ whose singular locus of codimension $ \geq 2$, then the canonical sheaf $\omega_Y$ of $Y$ could still be defined, see

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133253/how-to-define-the-canonical-sheaf-on-singular-varieties

Does adjunction formula still work now? i.e.

\begin{equation}
\omega_Y \stackrel{?}{=} \omega_{\mathbb{P}^n} \otimes \mathcal{O}(Y)|_Y
\end{equation}

More generally does adjunction formula work for general pairs $(Y,X)$ where $X$ is a smooth variety over a field $k$ and $Y$ is a singular hypersurface with singular locus of codimension $ \geq 2$?

Comment: What is canonical sheaf for you?

Comment: @Mohan It is the dualizing sheaf, and the general adjunction formula could be found from Vakil's note on algebraic geometry, which is what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Dualizing sheaf makes sense for any Cohen-Macaulay scheme. So, if $Y$ is a closed subset of a scheme $X$, of codimension $r$ and both Cohen-Macaulay, then $\omega_Y=\mathcal{E}xt^r(\mathcal{O}_Y,\omega_X)$. In particular, in the hypersurface case, the equality you write is correct. Singularities are not important.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you very much!